# Set up redirect so customer cannot view individual variant pages

Tags: magento2, configurable-product, magento-ce

Using config products, whilst setting variants of the config product as visible only to Search - I want to be able to keep those sorts of items to My Favourites in front-end.

I also want the user to not be able to access the URL of the variants and; ideally; be redirected back to the main product page itself for that variant.

Is this possible to set up at all?

Appreciate any help at all you can offer.

Comment: Please give more info detailed. So you have configurable product in which the sub products used in configurable products should not be shown individually to anyone who tried to visit the page. Same time is someone tried to visit sub products of configurable product then it should be redirected it to main product i.e configurable product. Is this the requirement?

Comment: That's exactly what I'd like to be able to do, yes. That way I can leave the Visibility for variants as Search only and they can still be added to Favourites. But a front-end user will always be redirected to the main product if they tried to go to the variant page(s)